# select() in C: the Rosetta stone?

Tags: c, select, file-io

Mostly [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) is straightforward in terms of what flags get set:

- r if data is readable,
- w if it's writeable,
- e for socket urgent data

But there are plenty of exceptions (or, perhaps, nontrivial extensions) to this rule: 'w' is set for a nonblocking connect that's completed, 'r' is set for a `listen()` with a pending `accept()`, and so on.

Has anyone found a straightforward list of what flags get set in what circumstances?

Comment: No, when a socket is closed it's marked as _readable_ with the `read` (or `recv`) call returning zero.

Comment: And if you read a [reference page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/connect.html), you will see that non-blocking connect being done is marking the socket as _writable_.

Comment: Don't use the exceptional set. It's essentially obsolete in all cases. Use readable notifications to retrieve pending error conditions, and forget about exceptions.

Comment: You know, I believe you're making my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this reference page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html):

> A descriptor shall be considered ready for reading when a call to an input function with `O_NONBLOCK` clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully. (The function might return data, an end-of-file indication, or an error other than one indicating that it is blocked, and in each of these cases the descriptor shall be considered ready for reading.)
>
> A descriptor shall be considered ready for writing when a call to an output function with `O_NONBLOCK` clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully.
>
> If a socket has a pending error, it shall be considered to have an exceptional condition pending. Otherwise, what constitutes an exceptional condition is file type-specific.

Except for descriptors in the exceptional set, it's pretty clear. If a blocking descriptor (no matter if it's a file, a socket, or some other descriptor) will not block, then it's marked as ready in its respective set. Accepting and receiving are "read" operations, while connection and writing are "write" operations.

The only problematic thing are the exceptional states, which depends on the type of descriptor you pass in the set.

Answer (score 0):

reference for select, which provide suggestion for usage of select

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.